# Crystal Reports using datasets that are not already created

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, crystal-reports, dataset

I am working for a Windows Application using WPF, c# in Visual Studio 2010 and Crystal Reports. I can create a report easily by adding a DataSet item to the project first, add tables to it and setting it as a datasource for the Report. What I need to do is create a dataset that can fetch data from tables that generate from time to time.

***For Ex- If the current year is 2012, the dataset should fetch information from table FEE_2012_2013, or if the current year is 2013, it should fetch the data from the Table FEE_2013_2014. I am creating these tables at runtime. How can I achieve this? Please help.***

Edit: I guess I need an alternative to STRONGLY TYPED DATASETS FOR CR.

Comment: creating tables at runtime?? can u elaborate?

Comment: Sir, with the time, my software will be creating newer tables automatically for storing data, say, month wise. So, as soon as April will come, it will generate a table called APRIL (or something) and start using it.

Comment: i did suggest you to create a Stored Procedure and pass the tablename as parameter - wouldnt be a easy task tho. Plus i dont really understand the need to create new new tables every month.

Comment: It was an example. I am creating new tables fro every academic year, APRIL 2012 to MARCH 2013, for example.

Comment: Can you please guide me more on that? Stored Procedure?

Comment: Any alternatives? I don't want to use a strongly typed dataset.

Answer (score 0):

> Here is an article on how you can come close to what you want:
>   Its quite complicated and you will have to spend some time on it to alter it to your requirements.

[Read this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21046/stored-procedure-to-return-dynamically-created-table-data)

> One of the quicker and better ways will be to just keep one table and add an additional column for an academic year.

Answer (score 0):

Just design the report with a generic table name, and then update the report schema at runtime to match the current database schema.

`myReport.Database.Tables("FEE").Location = "MyDatabase.dbo.FEE_2013_2014"`

[Table.Location](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table.Location%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version=v4.0%29;k%28DevLang-VB%29&rd=true)